# juno 5.0 install on ssd black screen

Tags: system-installation

all
Have new PC with  ssd 970 EVO Plus
Board is ASUS Prime B45M-A with integrated Graphics 
Install with usb stick Juno 5.0 provides the setup screen with options
F1-F5  have set nomodeset.
Install provides only blank screen. 
It must be something with the graphics .

any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can install Juno!
set parameters  : remove !!!!! quiet
add nomodeset!!!